# using javascript to toggle the display of other divs within the main div

Tags: javascript

The click of the button should toggle the visibility of that corresponding button's div. the first pic is what the code should look like from the start, and the second pic shows what the code should look like after clicking the submit button 1.

[image: this is what the div should initially look like]
[image: This is what the div should look like after clicking the 1st submit button]

```css
.toggleDiv{
    background: gray;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<body>
    <div class="toggleNav">
        <div class="Button1">
           <input onclick="toggleMain" type="image" src="images/vinylBtn.png">
            <a href="#">Button1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Button2">
            <input onclick="toggleMain" type="image" src="images/cdBtn.png">
            <a href="#">Button2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Button3">
            <input onclick="toggleMain" type="image" src="images/tapeBtn.png">
            <a href="#">Button3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toggleDiv">
        <div id="mainText">
            <h2>main div</h2>
            <p>This is where the different divs shouls be toggling
        </div>
        <div id="Button1">
            <p>This is the first div</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Button2">
            <p>This is the second div</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Button3">
            <p>This is the third div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you share your attempt in javascript?

Comment: Where is your `toggleMain` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all you elements by tag `a` in `toggleNav` and then add event listener. See my example in playground https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/ompaeL0d/29/:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll("div.toggleNav div a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length ; i++) {
    const divId = links[i].innerText
    links[i].addEventListener("click", 
    function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'block';
    }, 
    false);
}
```